# How do I hide a DIV based on a product array or category in the cart?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Like the title states, I am trying to hide a div based on an array of products or a category in the /cart.

We have a category called "DRTV". If a product from that category is in the cart, I want it to hide the "freeship" class.

I found some PHP from Bloomer that I've modified:

```
function bbloomer_find_id_in_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;     
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {

        $product = $values['data'];

        if ( in_array( 'DRTV', $categories ) ) {
            .freeship {display:none}
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me along the right path, here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (as Tagr mentioned) would be to add a class to the body via the [`body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) action/filter and hide it in your CSS based on that body class. Below is a working example.

The PHP looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'check_for_drtv' );
function check_for_drtv( $classes ) {
    $drtv_check = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( has_term( 'DRTV', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
            $drtv_check = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $drtv_check ) {
        $classes[] = 'drtv-in-cart';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

And then your CSS would simply be:

```
body.drtv-in-cart .freeship {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I needed it to do!

Absolutely perfect. Now, question, when I added .mainnav to the CSS string, it undid everything.

So, my code looked like this when I tried to hide the navigation.

`body.drtv-in-cart .freeship .mainnav {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: @MatthewTimmons that’s great, I’m happy it helped. do you mean you’re adding mainnav to the body class inside the php function, or are you adding it to the css rule? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Essentially, based on the product in the cart, I want to be able to hide the header, navigation, .freeship, and make it look like just cart page.

If you go to trydynatrap.com it's a redirect to a page on our main site. However, on that page, I have all those elements hidden. But when you go to the cart, it's just our normal /cart page. 

I'm able to hide the .freeship div, but now, I'd like to how the header, main nav and such as well based on the cart. 

I though it'd be as simple as just adding those items to the same CSS string.

Comment: @MatthewTimmons ah I see, you're code just needs to slightest adjustment to work, simply add a comma to separate the different elements that you want to hide. for example, if you want to hide BOTH the .header and the .footer elements, you would state `.header, .footer {display:none;}`

Comment: in your specific case it would probably be something like `body.drtv-in-cart #header-secondary-outer, body.drtv-in-cart #header-space, body.drtv-in-cart #header-outer, body.drtv-in-cart #footer-outer {display:none;}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing from the phone and memory, so sorry for not providing exact lines of code, however, the logic would follow in 3 steps.

1. Hook into "wp" action to check if WC()->cart has any product from DRTV category.
2. If you find any, add a filter to body_class() function, that usually is used on `<body>` tag. Basically you want to add a new class, something like "hide-freeshipping"
3. Then in your CSS file add line of code to hide products with freeshipping class whenever body has "hide-freeshipping" class.

Regards, T.